# I am Getting error corresponding frame work does not installed.(.net frame work 4.6.2)

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am having a net project. When I try to run it using VS 2012, it is telling that corresponding frame work does not installed.(.net frame work 4.6.2). But I have installed the frame work 4.6.2 that I know. But not able to run the project.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this. The reason for this is if we install .net frame work alone it may not be enough to develop the application but it may be enoough to run the application. In that case we might need to [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321) and install service pack/sdk/developer tool kit for that. Targeting to that framework.